# Unable to send keys within To (Email id) field on Compose E-mail page using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

The "**To**" Buttom is **unable to take keys** from selenium webdriver. In output it shows Unable to locate element. "To" is in iframe and I have used I frame but then also it not working.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class mail {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\mozilla   driver\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.mail.com/int/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-button']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys("rahulrahulxyz@mail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys("incredible");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-form']/button")).click();

        driver.switchTo().frame("thirdPartyFrame_home");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Compose E-mail")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.switchTo().frame("thirdPartyFrame_mail");     // **here is error**
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='idbd']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/input")).sendKeys("abcde@mail.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is hierarchical order in frames, then you need to switch to the parent frame -> then child frame. See if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the *Emailid* through `sendKeys()` method you have to switch back to the *defaultContent* first then switch again to the intended *frame* with *WebDriverWait* and finally induce *WebDriverWait* for the **To** field to be interactable and then send the *Emailid* as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("thirdPartyFrame_mail")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='compose-header_item compose-header_to mailobjectpanel-objectivation mailobjectpanel-textfield js-component mailobjectpanel']//div[@class='select2-container select2-container-multi js-select2']/ul/li/input"))).sendKeys("abcde@mail.com");
  ```
- Snapshot :

[image: Email-ID]

Comment: I understand all the codes except xpath. Can you explain me why you write such a xpath and why firebug xpath is not working. Using this type of xpath will waste lots of time for automating whole page. Is their any way to take out this type of xpath very easily. . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gdabzuXiaqonzI0ulnP8nkD6P53cAMKE

Comment: The xpath I have written simply mocks the dom and is a _logical xpath_. Firebug will provide you _absolute xpaths_ only. So you have to gradually move from using _absolute xpaths_ to _logical xpath_ which will provide the much needed stability.

Comment: Why not use a simple XPath like: //*[@id='idbd']//input

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank You Very Much. My problem is solved now.

Comment: @Frank There are multiple elements. To make the xpath unique I had to.

Comment: @DebanjanB you're right, I overlooked it. In that case  '(//*[@id='idbd']//input)[1]'  looks more stable to me.

Comment: @Frank But I won't resort to an _index_ until I run out of options :)

Comment: Do I have to write defaultContent every time whenever I need to send key in this iframe "mail". Like for sending keys in "subject" do I have to write first 2 lines of your code again.

Comment: @shovitmagar Whenever you need to change switch to a new frame always go back to the TopLevel Context (defaultContent) and then switch to the intended frame.

Comment: @Debanjan Right now I am run the same above code without making any changes. Their are 3 diff error are coming running at 3 diff times the same code above. Plz help me regarding this why this diff diff error are coming. Check this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1deIfD3VsoUqFeGbbtUYPC8Lr8Mi-3F0Y

Comment: @shovitmagar The errors are due to mismatch in compatibility between the binaries you are using. Upgrade your Selenium client, WebDriver variant and the WebClient variant to current levels.